# 2-х или 2-их. Как правильно пишется сокращение от слова "двоих"?

Tags: орфография, числительные, сокращения

Вроде второй вариант (**2-их**) кажется не очень подходящим, но, с другой стороны, первый (**2-х**) можно прочитать и как "двух". А речь идет именно о двоих (выплаты на двоих детей).

Если что — я понимаю, что лучше написать словом, но хотелось бы узнать и про правильное написание с цифрой.

Answer (score 3):

Пример из Семейного кодекса РФ:

> Алименты на **двух** детей назначаются в размере не менее трети от
>   совокупного дохода плательщика (ст. 81 СК РФ).

Если вам известна юридическая разница между "двумя" и "двоими" (как неделимой сущностью) детьми, тоже пишите словом; если её нет, а важно сэкономить побольше знакомест, то пишите отдельной цифрой. Приписывание же окончания от "двоих" к цифре было бы столь же неформальным, как в случаях "2-йственный", "2-рушник", 2-ежёнство или "2-ится", с экономией всего 1-2 знаков.

Answer (score 0):

В записи количественных числительных (т.е. тех, которые отвечают на вопрос «сколько») наращивание не используется.

Предпочтительный вариант — запись прописью: «выплаты на двух детей», допустимый — без наращивания: «выплаты на 2 детей».

**Update**

*Двое* — собирательное числительное, честно сказать не нашёл рекомендаций по поводу корректности замены оных цифровой записью, так что считаю, что действуют правила аналогичные количественным числительным, а если разница «двух — двоих» принципиальна, то следует использовать только запись прописью «выплаты на двоих детей».

---

[Материал](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99) от Gramota.ru по наращиванию.